# Use TypeScript to develop 3rd party JS scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript, clearscript

We use [ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript) to extend our apps, exporting C# objects into the JavaScript environment.

We'd like to use TypeScript to help develop these extending modules. These modules end in .RR for the main script and .RI for included library scripts.

How would we run tsc so that it takes the .TS file and out its transpilation as an .RR or .RI file?

Also, regarding the layout of `external.d.ts` are there any examples of defining .NET objects? For example, how to represent System.IO.File etc.

Comment: Compiling TS to JS and JS to RR/RI seems more straightforward.